# Realizar importação da schema alterando grant e synonym

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, importação

Em um ambiente tenho 5 *schemas* que fazem `grant` e `synonym` entre si, dos quais já estão funcionando.

Agora preciso duplicar esse ambiente padrão, para o ambiente do cliente, e preciso alterar o nome dos *schemas*, `grant` e `synonym`.

A parte de alterar o nome dos *schemas* resolvo no **IMPDP** dessa forma:

```
REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMAPADRAO:SCHEMACLIENTE
SCHEMAS=SCHEMAPADRAO
```

Mas sempre tenho que refazer os `grant` e `synonym` por estarem com nome incorretos.

Gostaria de resolver isso no próprio IMPDP, mas senão for possível gostaria de outra solução.

Answer (score 1):

Rode esses selects e execute o resultado.

```
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT',USERNAME) FROM ALL_USERS WHERE (USERNAME IN ('APEX_030200', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','ETC')) ORDER BY USER_ID;   

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT',USERNAME) FROM ALL_USERS WHERE (USERNAME IN ('APEX_030200', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','ETC')) ORDER BY USER_ID;

SELECT 'CREATE '|| decode(owner,'PUBLIC','PUBLIC ',null) ||
       'SYNONYM ' || decode(owner,'PUBLIC',null, owner || '.') ||
        lower(synonym_name) || ' FOR ' || lower(table_owner) ||
        '.' || lower(table_name) ||
        decode(db_link,null,null,'@'||db_link) || ';'
  from sys.dba_synonyms
  order by owner;
```

Comment: Não somente rodar, teria que alterar para fazer o DE / PARA, substituindo, e condições somente para os `schemas`, isso para os `grants`. Já para os `synonyn` alterar pra fazer o `CREATE OR REPLACE`, acho que daria certo pois dessa forma tenho todos os `grants` e `synonym` registrados. Vou esperar se existe uma forma direto no IMP de realizar isso. Obrigado Daniel